# Restrict the use of su only to a specific group

Tags: linux, pam, su

I have the task of "restricting the use of su by limiting access only to admin group"

How can I do this?

I am using Ubuntu.

Comment: man pam_wheel is probably a reasonable starting point.

Answer (score 2):

Access can be restricted with pam_wheel.

Open the /etc/pam.d/su and add there following line:

```
auth   required   pam_wheel.so   group=yourgroup
```

Alternatively, you can use:

```
auth required pam_succeed_if.so user ingroup admin
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# chgrp admin /bin/su
# chmod o-rwx /bin/su
```